# How to prove this Gaussian Mixture theorem? (Fitting/Overfitting)

Tags: probability-distributions, entropy, gaussian, elementary-proofs, formal-proof

Note from OP:  I gave up and reposted this Question with a Bounty on Cross Validated [HERE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219459/how-to-prove-this-gaussian-mixture-theorem-fitting-overfitting).

In certain applications, we approximate an unknown pdf by placing uniformly weighted Gaussian terms at each of some sample points $\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}
 $ and assigning some variances $\{\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{n}\} $:

$$f(x)\equiv\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}N(x-x_{i},\sigma_{i})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_{i}^{2}}}e^{-\frac{(x-x_{i})^{2}}{2\sigma_{i}^{2}}}$$

It seems intuitive that the sampled log-liklihood would be greater than (or equal to) the mean log-liklihood:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}ln(f(x_{j}))\geq\int f(x)ln(f(x))dx
 $$

This is obviously true for small variances (each $x_{i}$ is on top of a narrow Gaussian) and for very large variances (all $x_{i}$'s are together atop one broad Gaussian), and it's true for every random set of $x_i$'s and $\sigma_i$'s variances I've tried, but I can't prove it's true for all sets of variances $\{\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{n}\}$. I suspect Jensen's Inequality would be part of such a proof, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Why would you use $n$ different Gaussians if you have $n$ data points?

Comment: @DouglasZare  I know, it's a strange thing to do.  The reasons are a bit too involved to discuss here.

Comment: If you are actually doing this as opposed to having a thought experiment about overfitting, I hope you are regularizing the heck out of the parameters.

Comment: @DouglasZare  There's additional info that lets us select strategic x_i's and good values for the variance.  It's a long story.  I'm just stuck on this inequality.

Comment: This was cross-posted at Mathematics http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829100/how-to-prove-this-gaussian-mixture-theorem-fitting-overfitting and at Cross Validated http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219459/how-to-prove-this-gaussian-mixture-theorem-fitting-overfitting. Please don't do that.

Comment: @ToddTrimble  A user on Math SE told me I should post this on Math Overflow, and a user there said I'd have a better change of getting an answer if I posted on Stats SE.  What's the problem with posting on more than one board, when each board has different readers?

Comment: Duplication of effort, when people don't get to see what others have posted on the other sites, among other reasons.

Comment: @DouglasZare  But if I don't get an Answer at all because I posted on one site instead of the other, then everyone loses.

Comment: Different sites have different target audiences. The best policy is to decide which site is best and then post there; if no response comes after a few days, then it's generally okay with us (not so much with SE management) if you want to post it here, *provided* that you link, at each site where it is posted, to all the posts at other sites. I would guess that Cross Validated would have been best. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @ToddTrimble  Will do, and thank you for the info.  This was the first time I tried using MO or CV, and I wasn't aware of these issues.